# Join with relation to parent and grandparent

Tags: sql, hierarchical-query

Given the relation:

```
Teacher -> Students -> Advisors
```

There can also be

```
Teacher -> Advisors
```

How can I write a join statement that shows me null values for the students where advisors have their FK pointing towards teachers and not students? Without writing two separate select statements?

As of now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.teacherId, t.name,
    s.studentId, s.name,
    a.advisorId, a.name,
FROM
    teacher t 
JOIN
    student s ON t.teacherId = s.teacherId
JOIN 
    advisor ON s.studentId = a.personId
```

**Edit:** basically I want the result of the query below to be combined with the one above. But because the join in the middle (student) is missing for some FK's I expect those to be presented as null

```
SELECT 
    t.teacherId, t.name,
    a.advisorId, a.name,
FROM
    teacher t 
JOIN
    advisor ON s.teacherId = a.personId
```

Comment: Create the example with data at db-fiddle.com and attach the desired result.

Comment: is your `personId` is `studentId` and `teacherId` at the same time? Is there any `persontype` column available in your table? If not then you might able to do it perfectly. If  will return abnormal data for same `studentid` and `teacherid`.

Comment: Where u get the value a.personId. I don't see any table with name "a"

Comment: db-structure is fixed and i am i no position to change is im affraid

Comment: the missing a is a typo, its suppose to be after advisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
SELECT t.teacherId, t.name,
       s.studentId, s.name,
       a.advisorId, a.name
FROM teacher t JOIN
     student s
     ON t.teacherId = s.teacherId JOIN
     advisor a
     ON s.studentId = a.personId
UNION ALL
SELECT t.teacherId, t.name,
       NULL, NULL,
       a.advisorId, a.name
FROM teacher t JOIN
     advisor
     ON s.teacherId = a.personId
```

Comment: @PontusEkengren . . . So much for being 4 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

use UNION ALL:

```sql
SELECT t.teacherId, t.name,
       s.studentId, s.name,
       a.advisorId, a.name,
FROM teacher t 
JOIN student s
  ON t.teacherId = s.teacherId
JOIN advisor
  ON s.studentId = a.personId
UNION ALL
SELECT t.teacherId, t.name,
       null, null, 
       a.advisorId, a.name,
FROM teacher t 
JOIN advisor
  ON s.teacherId = a.personId
```